# ButtonToolbar with inline words in react-bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I want to render some words and a couple of Buttons in the same line. However, the ButtonToolBar seems to force it to be separated lines. Thus, is there anyway to make it in one line? That said, something like

some text ButtonToolBar{[Button1] [Button2]} some other text

```
<ButtonToolbar>
   Control: 
    <Button > Start </Button>
    <Button > End </Button>
   By xxx
 </ButtonToolbar>
```

Edit: if added , then they are indeed in the same long but wrong order.[image]

Answer (score 0):

But a ButtonGroup around your buttons

```
<ButtonToolbar>
   Control: 
    <ButtonGroup>
      <Button > Start </Button>
      <Button > End </Button>
    </ButtonGroup>
   By xxx
 </ButtonToolbar>
```

Comment: But this will result in wrong order. Please see my attachment in edit.

Comment: Maby try it with a `<Row>` tag

Answer (score 0):

I also have had a need to do this and found this question.

You can do this by creating divs in the ButtonToolbar and apply float: left; CSS. To make things easier and reusable I created a simple Message component - my need was to create a status message. I added some CSS to position the text nicely in the ButtonToolbar for the button size I was using. This could be enhanced by passing in a bootstrap button size and having the component position the text accordingly.

[image]

```js
<ButtonToolbar>
  <Button>Save</Button>
  <Button>Reset</Button>
  <Message>{this.state.statusMessage}</Message>
</ButtonToolbar>


// Message.js

import React from 'react';
import './Message.scss';

function Message(props) {
  return (
    <div className="button-toolbar-message">
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Message;


//Message.css:

.button-toolbar-message {
  float: left;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  color: grey;
}
```